# LAMP Stack and VPS Performance

Tags: mysql, php, apache-2.4, centos7, php-fpm

I have a VPS (Intel Xeon CPU E5-2630 v4 @ 2.20GHz, 4 cores - 8 GB RAM - 200 GB SSD) and I am using it to host a Wordpress blog. I am using Virtualmin as a control panel, The operating system is Centos 7.

I am having performance issues, and I don't know where to start.

```
top - 21:22:16 up 18:09,  1 user,  load average: 9.56, 5.84, 3.38
Tasks: 201 total,   7 running, 194 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 90.2 us,  9.4 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.3 si,  0.1 st
KiB Mem :  8008656 total,   801596 free,  3099284 used,  4107776 buff/cache
KiB Swap: 10485756 total,  9760492 free,   725264 used.  4302252 avail Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 1722 mysql     20   0 4083800   1.7g   4140 S  66.2 22.1 371:01.54 mysqld
31511 fooshya   20   0  628688 104348  32320 R  34.8  1.3   1:52.20 php-fpm
31582 fooshya   20   0  604552  81988  34116 R  33.8  1.0   2:03.97 php-fpm
31585 fooshya   20   0  632392 113924  39844 R  32.5  1.4   1:36.74 php-fpm
22897 fooshya   20   0  641040 120832  36444 S  32.1  1.5  19:49.99 php-fpm
31587 fooshya   20   0  585320  68164  41188 R  31.1  0.9   1:41.48 php-fpm
22880 fooshya   20   0  939132 143248  47484 S  26.2  1.8  20:49.46 php-fpm
22888 fooshya   20   0  654676 130512  34744 R  25.5  1.6  17:42.91 php-fpm
22883 fooshya   20   0  651084 134228  39416 S  23.8  1.7  19:36.57 php-fpm
31586 fooshya   20   0  725716  67072  45660 S  19.2  0.8   2:16.77 php-fpm
 2699 root      20   0  199676  88352   3156 R  16.9  1.1   0:01.40 /usr/libex+
31525 fooshya   20   0  599108  77260  34660 S  14.2  1.0   1:12.42 php-fpm
 2698 root      20   0  572180  63264  39288 S   4.3  0.8   0:01.72 php-cgi
    1 root      20   0  191312   3064   1668 S   1.3  0.0   0:34.44 systemd
  553 dbus      20   0   58444   1068    672 S   1.0  0.0   0:26.30 dbus-daemon
 3501 named     20   0  540292 120020   2472 S   1.0  1.5   1:34.29 named
  369 root      20   0   81196  34516  34360 S   0.7  0.4   0:31.72 systemd-jo+
```

I tried various configurations of Apache, PHP FPM, MySQL, but the website still became unresponsive many times during the day.

I appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Additional information request. 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
A) PHP configuration. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: If you still need assistance, please post additional information requested on June 4, 2020.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's clearly a problem with the plugins on your website. Your VPS should be able to handle 100 times this trafic (if everything was well optimized).

You need to find the faulty script. Setup a simple load test with any performance testing tool (record one visit and simulate thousand users doing the same). Then disable some plugins, test performance, disable some other plugin, test performance again... You'll quickly found the slow plugins.

Changing the VPS for a more powerful one will not change much. Hardware hardly compensate poor software.

Also enable a cache plugin if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Most of your CPU time is spent by PHP code, so you will need to start disabling all the plugins and modules and see if it makes a significant difference. If you can't, you need to profile the PHP code that is running and see what parts of the code are consuming most CPU and start there.

If you are not up to that, you need to weigh up the cost of hiring a PHP professional against the cost of renting a VPS server with more CPU power.

Comment: Thanks @gordan for your answer
Can you please advise me about the sufficient VPS specifications to host a wordpress blog with about 2000 visits a day?

Comment: Unit of computational complexity is not "visit". Double it, and see if you still run out. If you do, double it again. Keep doubling until it can keep up.